# How do I use the encog data formats for audio classification with hidden markov models?

Tags: java, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, encog

I am trying to classify audio data with MFCC and an Hidden Markov Model. 
I am using the encog java library.

I have a working [MFCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) implementation and get 13 coefficients out of it.

I can't get it to work probably, I think my biggest problem is the understanding of the data format encog uses.

For training I have an array that holds all MFCC-vectors of the training data plus an array for information for supervised learning for each vector.
Right now, I am simply tossing this in an BasicMlSequenceSet.

This "works", in terms of it doesn't throw an exception.

Classification works similiar, i put the MFCC vector in an BasicMLDataSet and call the probability-method of the hmm.
It throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here.

What am I doing wrong? I know I should normalize the features before using them, but how? Should I use a different data format here?

Sorry for the vagueness, but I am really stuck here and can't seem to get it to work. I am a little bit desperate here, so if anyone could help me out a little bit I would be more than thankful.

Comment: You could write to encog developers directly: https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I gave it a try.

Comment: can you please provide samples of your data?